# Хочу знать ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Я хочу научиться делать сайты на `ASP.NET`, но **не хочу переделывать уже готовые примеры из учебников**, с чего посоветуете начать?? Быть может подадите идею какого либо веб приложения, а я постараюсь его реализовать на `ASP.NET`.

Comment: Я хочу стать бойцом без правил, но не хочу боксировать грушу и тренироваться у стенки, с чего посоветуете начать?? Может кто-то поломает мне пару ребер сначала? или посоветуете район с гопниками? Или скажите на кого нарваться, а я постараюсь дать ему по морде =)

Comment: Ну, как то так...

Comment: Хорошо, тогда посоветуйте, где взять хорошую грушу на ASP.NET WebForms VB.NET???

Comment: @niki-timofe, вы со своими вопросами.....двусмысленности что ли создаете.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Идей уйма, вы хотя бы написали что конкретно Вам нравится. Можно ведь и сайт о котятках написать и сайт об оружии , и браузерную игру, и веб - IDE для программирования, и ещё over   9000 всего.

Comment: Сайт о котятках и об оружии это 3-4 класс HTML в блокноте...
Web-IDE - это Java (Script) + HTML
Браузерная игра - не плохо, подайте идею пожалуйста....

Comment: Что значит подайте идею? Всегда удивляли такие вопросы, требования, просьбы. А сайт о котятках и оружии можно сделать и не уровня 3-4 класс.